# Backup and restore of Core Data (SQLite) using XML file and Google Drive API

Tags: ios, core-data, google-drive-api

I have an iPad app (XCode 4.6, Storyboards, ARC, iOS 6.x and Core Data SQLite store).  I have noticed that when I make any change to the Core Data store such as adding/removing an attribute, the old store is deleted and the user has to enter all of their information again, which is unacceptable for this app.  So, my thought was to do a *backup and restore* from a XML file stored offline at the beginning and end of the app's execution.  I want to store this using the Google Drive API, rather than iCloud.

Is this a good solution to my issue?  If not, suggestions of a better way of doing this?

SD

Comment: Have you heard about migrations? Link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration

Comment: Please re-write your comment *as an answer*... this is *exactly* what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: The question is interesting even though the motivation here is wrong. One could want to provide an export/import mechanism to and from a CoreData DB (to be used by external software, or as a manual backup).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better way to solve your problem is use of so called "migrations".

Tutorial link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration